# how to enable ssl in jboss 7.0.0.GA

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, ejb, tls1.2

I want to implement SSL for ejb call. I tried via the following link, but its not working as expected.

[enable SSl in jboss](https://gist.github.com/thjanssen/b69434413207e439553b)

How to enable SSL in Jboss 7.0.0.GA for EJB calls.

Comment: Do you mean community project JBoss AS 7 (really old one) or Red Hat product JBoss EAP 7 (not so old, but still old)?

Comment: @kwart For Jboss EAP 7.0.0. I tried the following steps in the link [ssl config](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/#secure_the_management_interfaces) but i can hitting the server and call ejb with out client certificate from client side. But My management console working fine fro https after setup.But EJB i.e. Application not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial for WildFly 10 - http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2783

What you need to change in server configuration is:

- add SSL as your identity in a SecurityRealm
- configure HTTPs listener in undertow subsystem
- configure connector in remoting subsystem which will use the https
- reference the new remoting connector from ejb3 subsystem

Sample CLI:

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=ApplicationRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(keystore-path=server.keystore, keystore-relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir, keystore-password=123456)
reload
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:add(socket-binding=https, security-realm=ApplicationRealm)
/subsystem=remoting/http-connector=https-remoting-connector:add(connector-ref=https, sasl-protocol=remote, security-realm=ApplicationRealm)
/subsystem=ejb3/service=remote:write-attribute(name=connector-ref,value=https-remoting-connector)
reload
```

Then you should use the proper port (8443) in the EJB client configuration.